# Delphi - Autenticação OAuth 1.0 - WooCommerce Api Rest

Tags: delphi, rest, woocommerce, oauth

Olá, estou tentando fazer um 'POST' na API Rest do WooCommerce utilizando Delphi. Já fiz vários testes utilizando uma lib. que baixei em http://sourceforge.net/projects/oauthdelphi/ mas sem sucesso. Então, como agora existe a palete 'RestClient', tentei com 'TRestClient', 'TRestRequest', 'TOAuth1Authenticator' e no ultimo eu informo apenas a 'consumer_key' e a 'consumer_secret', mas ele passa as informações [oauth_consumer_key, oauth_timestamp, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature, and oauth_signature_method] no cabeçalho, mas devem ser passadas como query string.

> The OAuth parameters must be added as query string parameters and not
>   included in the Authorization header. This is because there is no
>   reliable cross-platform way to get the raw request headers in
>   WordPress.

No demo 'REST-Library :: Demos', não tem nenhum exemplo do fluxo OAuth 1.0a (One Leg).
Enfim, gostaria de saber como faço pra enviar os parâmetros como query string, utilizando os componentes, ou se existe outra forma de enviar esta requisição para a API.

```
OAuth1Authenticator1.ConsumerKey := 'ck_f972e91046ea920e8b7c8141e1df516d7eea47b8';
OAuth1Authenticator1.ConsumerSecret := 'cs_adc97ab54caffe1c06b7f8dbb0c07de0adaa3f92';
OAuth1Authenticator1.SigningClassName := 'TOAuth1SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1';
OAuth1Authenticator1.CallbackEndpoint := '';
//oauth1.Authenticate(RESTRequest1);

RESTClient1.Authenticator := OAuth1Authenticator1;

RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'http://localhost/wordpress/wc-api/v2';

RESTRequest1.Resource := 'products';

RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('title', 'produto teste', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);

RESTRequest1.Execute;

if assigned(RESTResponse1.JSONValue) then
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Text := TJson.Format(RESTResponse1.JSONValue)
end
else
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(RESTResponse1.Content);
end;
```

Comment: Ola Will! Vc poderia colocar seu código aqui par nos mostrar o que já tentou fazer.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei o código. Inclusive, ja tentei várias vezes com o Postman e também não consigo executar um POST, já com a 'WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library-master' PHP funciona.